# How do I perform a network request on multiple items in Kotlin asynchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine

I have a list of items that I need to retrieve from a web service.  It seemed like the best way to do this would be via a Channel, but I can't get them to run at the same time.  For simplicity sake, I have reduced my problem to a small application with a loop that simulates the network call.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.random.Random

private val charPool: List<Char> = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')
private val sdf =SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.SSSS")
const val NUMBER_OF_LOOPS = 5

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val channel = Channel<String>()
    log("First thing")
    repeat(NUMBER_OF_LOOPS) {
        launch {
            channel.send(getValue(it))
        }
    }
    log("Second Thing")
    launch {
        repeat(NUMBER_OF_LOOPS) {
            val value = channel.receive()
            log(value)
        }
    }
    log("All Done.")
}

fun getValue(i: Int): String {
    log(String.format("Starting value for %d", i))
    var rand: String = ""
    repeat(100000) {
        rand = (1..256)
            .map { Random.nextInt(0, charPool.size) }
            .map(charPool::get)
            .joinToString("")
    }
    log(String.format("Done processing for %d", i))
    return rand
}

fun log(value: String){
    println(String.format("%s %s", sdf.format(Date()), value))
}
```

When I run this, I get the following output.

```
2019-11-20 10:57:00.0473 First thing
2019-11-20 10:57:00.0484 Second Thing
2019-11-20 10:57:00.0485 All Done.
2019-11-20 10:57:00.0495 Starting value for 0
2019-11-20 10:57:02.0489 Done processing for 0
2019-11-20 10:57:02.0495 Starting value for 1
2019-11-20 10:57:03.0898 Done processing for 1
2019-11-20 10:57:03.0898 Starting value for 2
2019-11-20 10:57:05.0270 Done processing for 2
2019-11-20 10:57:05.0270 Starting value for 3
2019-11-20 10:57:06.0607 Done processing for 3
2019-11-20 10:57:06.0607 Starting value for 4
2019-11-20 10:57:07.0930 Done processing for 4
2019-11-20 10:57:07.0930 YxjtbzPR29etkoCg6yR64XwepRPDHGaS8MAp4M16FLyEIaVUcqtx6RSaBaWmB5MyDh60Xo7a6aOSfwmLOvdt2Ppyj3K8OpWjhQ5BuC6aHVrPmQwau5PLROIWSIU0wrLl7mrYhDJSSfFPRUATXxFz0viDvzx4q88q8Nm9b3LPu264bR0kYrQk2sGQATQLRxR7DcsgKAvCvFKy8Ba0VYcKreJKAWOeUVYkvFTW9rPJ2X8FkwhzqeuNlWeK27v60CSB
2019-11-20 10:57:07.0930 n9uOCwuIlKX4PcWcFUhKfr96Topoht67h0wt1JHTAzIGxaRnHd92wW3wdghWaPxL9WuCE2ICfwHY5NCq1PYAekaCKEPvb46Ouz4TzFgGy0j3xZdwgyVqS4pmQJvl7hvhjldvouhxFfkt1DLeNAyai7J2CMFvWhDsFsNy0S0jsJfMfI9TV9N7U02u74rnwR5hZb2RfLJgfYf77GtS8jkf0QXufnhJmt8MYsx7BGLi9vrhgH0qcaLdA2bDspia767s
2019-11-20 10:57:07.0930 ljfUduDQunB2YsHI0ZO7HRXEbqSbozIKivbge0DIFuNgI7cAvPIofQhBiVU2sTfhswr9zpRd30aKZzE3zprU5oPg70RuTSAAbDaVr06nd4IARi8WbfthpPVP3FIk4ScezMH4I47FmoNuwMmTxyLrtskWWqInJn8WA0U7Riq4pNG7y8CKiXgiytWH09QXJvNMG7Wzd3ApIUyx45ljCOZUHDiORsGWRcQnf9ngv56d9qGBYJOqfHKALiJnca9CoJSN
2019-11-20 10:57:07.0931 LkoTs8Oa8cxd3NUEKK1snRZPguYFTtDQJcJ4kYDaDYpjBOScnziEbr2OuLsCHfXgBNFc3ZzejKCLwN3oCT5l24iILkpm7122ktoOGPXtMwNBoEuB4oK83xqm6P7YKX7YU3LK1njio5zzdbPhfc0Qyrym1qyBVQnr3c4dJds1zMYDTAfZJ0o8Wyi5R8XJ7bH8aiCXziozaEELa80CWM3mDymjSWMnihDjfJlasO3cFHP4q2vpsLzqnxqTfS9WKGNv
2019-11-20 10:57:07.0931 6wDtTynt8htbfm28ipVHOZ961TdoLZomAk2cv7GzvptFqlKnU71Y5U22n75i9AQloZpFAbGdEXHduYKWoAHvi8mmPCmK7X1y8wUjqHWYEC4GFgGbrzM4lIPAKp1WagqnL3gndpGMPwY1WpiXtpjqtgGCNb26TEsF178uXgMHk5i8V46bBBNGPFPTtACCn5Ga5myv7GAcwWpGcl4yHkBpxSVuqA1bhssJ4KhIvwexPH159ePeeaixeIBZQTfwDl86
```

I would expect all of the "Starting value..." logs to show up before any of the "Done Processing" logs, but as you can see they are all running synchronously.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that the coroutine scope in which the child coroutines are launched is provided by `runBlocking`, which actually [runs everything in the current thread](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#unconfined-vs-confined-dispatcher) by default, which in this case is your `main` thread. This context is inherited by the children coroutines created by `launch`. You can easily see this if you add the output of `Thread.currentThread().name` to your `log` function.

Specify the dispatcher as an argument to `runBlocking` e.g.:

```
runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }
```

That being said, I feel like you are complicating things with channels. You could just use `async` to make these requests concurrent.

For example, if you change your `main` method to the following:

```
// Note the explicit specification of the dispatcher here...
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit>(Dispatchers.Default) {
  log("First thing")

  val results = (1..NUMBER_OF_LOOPS).map {
    async { getValue(it) }
  }.awaitAll()

  log("Results: $results")

  log("All Done.")
}
```

it should output something like the following, which I think is what you were looking for. Note I added the thread name to your `log` method for additional insight:

```
DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 2019-11-20 14:51:23.0884 Starting value for 3
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 2019-11-20 14:51:23.0884 Starting value for 1
DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 2019-11-20 14:51:23.0884 Starting value for 4
DefaultDispatcher-worker-6 2019-11-20 14:51:23.0884 Starting value for 5
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 2019-11-20 14:51:23.0884 Starting value for 2
DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 2019-11-20 14:51:25.0547 Done processing for 3
DefaultDispatcher-worker-6 2019-11-20 14:51:25.0599 Done processing for 5
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 2019-11-20 14:51:25.0601 Done processing for 1
DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 2019-11-20 14:51:25.0775 Done processing for 4
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 2019-11-20 14:51:25.0779 Done processing for 2
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 2019-11-20 14:51:25.0780 Results: [U5VZ..., J4u0..., HWqg..., 1VrO..., ecS1...]
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 2019-11-20 14:51:25.0780 All Done.
```

If you do not call `awaitAll()` you will get a list of `Deferred<T>`, which you can compose e.g.

```
val first = (1..x).map {
  async { something(it) }
}

val second = (1..y).map {
  async { somethingElse(it) }
}

(first + second).awaitAll()
```

I recommend reading [Composing Suspending Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html#composing-suspending-functions), especially the section about structured concurrency. Handling failures properly with async functions can be tricky, and needs additional attention before putting this kind of code into production.